# Fast concatenating of lists

Tags: performance, data-structures

In my program I calculate very much concatenations of lists with single items (i. e. I often perform "`concatenate(someList, <single-sized list containing one item>)`" operations). How to make those concatenations and iterating through resultant lists as fast as possible?

I have considered two implementations but may be there is faster one:

- Naive implementation of concatenation by copying all items to resultant list. That results in O(n) time cost of iterating but also O(n) performance of concatenating.
- Wrapping result of concatenation into new class, `ListsConcatenation` (which also has interface of `List`), which keeps references to all original lists and forwards all calls to corresponding one. That will result in O(1) time cost of concatenating but time cost of iterating will become O(n*log(n)).

Comment: Please post your data-structure for the list.

Comment: Option 2 will also reflect changes made to the component lists after they have been concatenated, which Option 1 does not. And one could easily construct infinitely looping lists with Option 2.

Comment: Please tell us the programming language you are using

Comment: @Lavir the Whiolet: Why is the cost of iterating through option 2 O(n lg n)? If ListsConcatenation returns an iterator that iterates through each one, and when it gets to the end of one list just goes straight on to the next one then you have no performance penalty? Did you mean random access is O(nlgn)? This is also not true if the ListsConcatenation can access each list's size, as it can then choose which index has the desired value, and iterate through that in O(n) steps (or access it directly if an arraylist in O(1))...?

Comment: (I'm assuming the n you use in the question is the size of each list, not the sum of the sizes of all the lists)

Comment: When I have one list with one item, I get "list(item)". When I concatenate it with another list, I get "lists_con(list(item), list(item)". When I concatenate it with yet another list, I get "lists_con(lists_con(list(item), list(item)), list(item))". Etc. Just count how much calls (and "unfoldings" of "ListsContinuation") will be needed to just get first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this requirement pops up when populating a list in left-to-right order. If so, then the question is not how to insert a single element in O(1) time, but how to insert *n* elements in O(*n*) time, and the simple answer is to build the list back-to-front and reverse it at the end.

I am, of course, assuming some functional language that provides immutable data types. If your data types are mutable, then you could simply remember the last node, and append a new element by assigning to its `next` pointer.

Comment: All structures in my program are immutable.

Comment: @Lavir: I'm glad to hear it. Immutable data types are usually a much better choice.

Comment: In such an algorithm concatenation will have O(1) time cost and iterating will have O(n) time cost. Please correct me if I'm not right.

Comment: @Lavir: From your question, I surmised (even though you didn't state it) that you are trying to create a list of elements. My solution creates a list of *n* elements in O(*n*) time, which amounts to the same thing as performing *n* appends, each taking O(1) time. If this is not what you are doing, then my answer is not suitable.

Comment: That's what am I doing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Write a Linked List that has a pointer to the end node as well as a pointer to the head. To concatenate a list in O(1), dereference the "end" pointer of the list that you want to go first, and make that node's "next" pointer point to the head of the list you want to append. Remember to update the end point to point to the node referenced by the appended list's "end" pointer...

Comment: I need to create new list, leaving original lists intact.